# Spring MVC returning view throws 500 error

Tags: ajax, spring, jqgrid

I'm building Spring MVC web application.

There're two views for a list and a specific view of a choosen data.

In the list view, there's a Jqgrid.

When an user clicks one of the rows in the list, then this ajax call should be made.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/view.do",
        data : { pBen: 3 },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

I set `@RequestMapping` in the controller. So, when the ajax runs, the method mapped by the annotation is called with no problem. ( I've tested this in debugging mode. )

after fetching the requested data, I do these things below on ModelAndView object.

```
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();       
mv.addObject("ri", resultInfo);
mv.addObject("pd", personInfo);
mv.setViewName("SYS/SYS01/view");
return mv;
```

The actual file path is exactly the same as I defined in the parameter of setViewName.

But first, it throws 500 error on client side.

```
POST http://192.168.1.189:8080/view.do500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
send jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
n.extend.ajax jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
(anonymous function) VM241:4
n.event.dispatch jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3
r.handle
```

And what happens inside is like this.

```
2014. 7. 6 pm 6:57:26 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
: Servlet.service() for servlet Paas threw exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'SYS/SYS01/view' in servlet with name 'Paas'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Am I wrong with the returning view phase?
Other views work just fine. I just wrote almost same codes like above.

but only this view gives me 500 error.

how can I fix this?

Comment: Show, please, the path to your view within WAR. And how you configure `ViewResolver`

Comment: How you configure you route paths?. Do you have a view.xml? there you have the name SYS/SYS01/view associated with html/jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" >
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
                    <property name="prefix" value="/ui/" />
                    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
```

found out what caused 500 error.

As Artem Bilan mentioned above on the comment, it was ViewResolver settings.
The target jsp was located in `/ui/SYS/.....` and I missed removing the leading **'/'** in `ViewResolvers prefix setting`